# Update JavaFX ImageView's image?

Tags: java, javafx, imageview

I have a ImageView nested in a Stackpane in my JavaFX application:

**UiManager.java**

```
 @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        logger.info("Starting UI...");

        //Set the application icon.
        primaryStage.getIcons().add(getImage(ICON_APPLICATION));

        try {
            mainWindow = new MainWindow(primaryStage, logic);
            mainWindow.show(); //This should be called before creating other UI parts
            mainWindow.fillInnerParts();

        } catch (Throwable e) {
            logger.severe(StringUtil.getDetails(e));
            showFatalErrorDialogAndShutdown("Fatal error during initializing", e);
        }
    }
```

**MainWindow.java**

```
// Independent Ui parts residing in this Ui container
private ImagePanel imagePanel;
private PersonListPanel personListPanel;
private ResultDisplay resultDisplay;
private HelpWindow helpWindow;

@FXML
private StackPane imagePlaceholder;

@FXML
private StackPane commandBoxPlaceholder;

@FXML
private MenuItem helpMenuItem;

@FXML
private StackPane personListPanelPlaceholder;

@FXML
private StackPane resultDisplayPlaceholder;

@FXML
private StackPane statusbarPlaceholder;

void fillInnerParts() {
        imagePanel = new ImagePanel();
        imagePlaceholder.getChildren().add(imagePanel.getRoot());

        personListPanel = new PersonListPanel(logic.getFilteredPersonList(), logic.selectedPersonProperty(),
                logic::setSelectedPerson);
        personListPanelPlaceholder.getChildren().add(personListPanel.getRoot());

        resultDisplay = new ResultDisplay();
        resultDisplayPlaceholder.getChildren().add(resultDisplay.getRoot());

        StatusBarFooter statusBarFooter = new StatusBarFooter(logic.getAddressBookFilePath(), logic.getAddressBook());
        statusbarPlaceholder.getChildren().add(statusBarFooter.getRoot());

        CommandBox commandBox = new CommandBox(this::executeCommand, logic.getHistory());
        commandBoxPlaceholder.getChildren().add(commandBox.getRoot());

        //imagePlaceholder.getChildren().add(imagePanel.getRoot());
    }
```

**ImagePanel.java**

```
public class ImagePanel extends UiPart<Region> {

    private static final String FXML = "ImagePanel.fxml";

    @FXML
    private ImageView imageView;

    public ImagePanel() {
        super(FXML);
        imageView.setImage(new Image("/assets/1.png"));
    }

    public void updateView() {
        imageView.setImage(new Image("/assets/3.png"));
    }
}
```

I extracted the relevant parts considering i am actually modifying an existing project.

Here I tried to create a separated method `updateView()` which I would call in another class in my program as `new ImagePanel().updateView()`

But in this case, no matter how I seem to call `updateView()`, the image does not change.

Comment: What prevents you from calling `ImageView#setImage()` with the desired `Image` instance?

Comment: I have tried that but it doesn't seem to change the image at all.

Comment: Than could you show us how you changed the image?

Comment: Thanks, I added more details about the implementation in my question proper.

Comment: You do realise when calling `new ImagePanel(). updateView()` you are creating a new (unrelated) instance right? (Ever read/heard about static vs non-static in java?). In short: get hold of the instance inside `MainWindow` and call `updateView` on that for it to work.

Comment: Hi @c0der sorry for the lack of reply I did not get a chance to revisit the question. Yes, your code works fine I'm sorry the question in particular wasn't explicit enough - I figured out with the tip above :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** the question was changes after posting this answer.

This is an MVCE that does what you need (slow startup because it uses web resources). 
Run, and then swap it with your images to verify:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test extends Application{

    private static int counter =0;
    private ImageView iv;
    private Image[] images;
    private final String[] urls = {
            "https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/160/lg/57/tropical-fish_1f420.png",
            "https://www.shareicon.net/data/128x128/2015/03/28/14104_animal_256x256.png",
            "https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/DarkGlass_Reworked/128x128/apps/gnome-fish.png",
            "http://www.iconsalot.com/asset/icons/freepik/pet-shop-13/128/010-fish-2-icon.png"
    };

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        images = new Image[urls.length];
        for(int i=0; i< urls.length; i++) {
            images[i] = new Image(urls[i]);
        }

        iv = new ImageView(images[counter++]);
        Button swapImage = new Button("Swap Image");
        swapImage.setOnAction(e->swapImage());
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(iv);
        root.setBottom(swapImage);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.sizeToScene();
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void swapImage() {
        counter = counter +1 >= images.length ? 0 : counter;
        iv.setImage(images[counter++]);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I take it that simply calling `.setImage` should refresh the GUI with the new image?

Comment: Yes. Did you run it ? Does it work ? try using it with your images. Are you using Eclipse IDE ?